# Format DateTime.ParseInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, kendo-grid

Good morning,

I have problem with format of datetime which comes in format "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)".

```
var value = "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)";
DateTime.Parse(value) throws CastException.
```

I have also tried use ParseExact method which is more powerfull but still without access

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)",
        "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0000 (Central Europe Daylight Time)'",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)",
        "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)'",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Everything fails ...

I also wanted try hack and make a SubString(4,11) but IE returns diferent format than chrome so it's not usable ...

I am sending it from kendo filter in grid.

So my questions are:

1) Is there way how to parse this format vith C#?

2) Is there way how to say to Kendo filter "send another format"? Format and ParseFormats ignores me ...

My expected format in which I want format is dd.MM.yyyy ..
Thank you for help

Edit:
My kendo code looks like:

```
.....
{
            field: "DateField",
            type: "date",
            width: "110px",
            template: function (e) {
                return $.format.date(e.DateField, "dd.MM.yyyy");
            },
            filterable: {
                extra: true,
                operators: {
                    date: {
                        gt: "Is greater than",
                        lt: "Is less than"
                    }
                },
                ui: function (element) {
                    element.kendoDatePicker({
                        format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: In which format do you want to convert this date?

Comment: Kendo has an utility API which you can use to format the date _before_ sending it to the server. Format the date using a supported .Net DateTime format.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I edited this information into question. I also inserted part of time in which I am creating filter in kendo. 
 
@Andrei Can you post me link to documentation or something please? Because I didn't find anything like that..

Comment: [Sure!](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting)

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I will have a look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ParseExact():

```
using System.Globalization; 

var value = "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)";
var trimedValue = value.Substring(0, value.IndexOf(" ("));
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(trimedValue, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DateTime.Parse` code fails because your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for that string. None of culture can have this kind of format. A `DateTime` timezone awareness by the way.

Your `ParseExact` examples fails because; first one has `+0200` for offset but your string has `+0000`. This remains for second one and also your timezones are different. (`Central Europe Daylight Time` and `GMT Standard Time`)

Since you have [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) part in your string, I would choose `DateTimeOffset` parsing with [`"K"` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#KSpecifier) instead like;

```
string s = "Mon Jun 15 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Central Europe Daylight Time)'", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                 DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{15.06.2015 00:00:00 +02:00}` and I think this *might* be the best thing you can get.